# Array Input Compilation Error in UDF SQL Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Actually I am passing I_UserName as array parameter in UDF and then FLATTEN to table for comparing the rows. I am trying to avoid in clause based queries therefore taking array as input parameter.

> 001044 (42P13): SQL compilation error: error line 8 at position 40
>
> Invalid argument types for function 'PARSE_JSON': (ARRAY)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fntuserList_New (I_UserName array, I_UserAge array)
RETURNS TABLE (Id int, UserName varchar(256), UserAge int)
AS 
$$
            SELECT
                Idx AS Id,
                ul.UserName,
                ul.UserAge 
            FROM  
                UserLoad ul
            INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(input => PARSE_JSON(I_UserName)) AS usr 
            ON UPPER(usr.VALUE::string) = UPPER(ul.UserName)
        $$;
```

Comment: Hi - you haven’t actually asked a question? What don’t you understand? The PARSE_JSON function doesn’t take an array as an input parameter, as the documentation clearly states it takes a string input: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json

Comment: Actually I am passing I_UserName as array parameter in UDF and then FLATTEN to table for comparing the rows. I am trying to avoid in clause based queries therefore taking array as input parameter

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. You are passing I_UserName (an array input parameter) into the PARSE_JSON function. FLATTEN is running against the result of the PARSE_JSON function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to remove the PARSE_JSON function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fntuserList_New (I_UserName array, I_UserAge array)
RETURNS TABLE (Id int, UserName varchar(256), UserAge int)
AS 
$$
    SELECT
        Idx AS Id,
        ul.UserName,
        ul.UserAge 
    FROM  
        UserLoad ul
    INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(input => I_UserName ) AS usr 
    ON UPPER(usr.VALUE::string) = UPPER(ul.UserName)
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

`PARSE_JSON(I_UserName)` can't accept an array as input.

`I_UserName` is an array, as defined in the function header:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fntuserList_New (I_UserName array, I_UserAge array)
```

Either change the definition of the function, or convert that array to something that `PARSE_JSON()` can parse.